# heroku No module named _sqlite3

Tags: django, heroku, sqlite, pinax

While trying to deploy a django app on heroku, I get the following error. I am able to test locally. It works fine. But "heroku run python manage.py syncdb" results in the following error. I have gone through some of the other related posts, but could not find satisfactory answer.

I have python 2.7, and django 1.3 and using sqlite3 as db. I am trying to deploy the following on heroku - https://github.com/Stackato-Apps/pinax-social. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 257, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import connection
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 32, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 34, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading %s: %s" % (module, exc))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named _sqlite3
```

Comment: Well it seems either those packages are missing or they are missing from your python path

Comment: You can't use sqlite3 on Heroku. You'll need to use postgres.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku dosen't support SQLite3, you should configure your app with Postgres as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#database-settings